# How do I add text above a HTML5 canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, text

This is probably very easy, but I suck at web development, so here goes; I am currently rewriting my website (if you've seen it, you'll know why) and I've written a script that handles a nice background. The background is in a HTML5 `<canvas>` element. I now wish to be able to write text, for example using `<p>` tags, and have it show above the canvas (so that it is hovering above the canvas). How would I achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean, "above"? physically hovering over the contents of the canvas? or physically earlier in the document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you'll benefit from knowing about:

- Positioning. In CSS, you can position things 'absolutely', so that things can stack one on top of the other
- z-index. z-index helps the browser understand how you want stacked items to layer; if the `<p>` tag has a higher z-index than the canvas, it'll be shown over the canvas, and vice versa.

---

Further reading:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/z-index